# SymemtricDS Multi-Tier Data Monitoring

Tags: symmetricds

I have 3 tier nodes (`corp`, `store`, `device`) and have `item` table each node.

Let say, I want to add monitoring data of `item` table to `monitoring` table. The `monitoring` table shows `time` and `current_node` of the data currently.

How to do centralized monitoring from the `corp` that tell the data is arrived to `device`?
Especially it doesn't edit the SymmetricDS' generated structure.

My past idea is requiring to edit the trigger. Any ideas?

The scenario is:

1. `corp` input the data
2. `corp` also input data monitor that tells `time` and `current_node` (`corp`)
3. The data is syncing to `store`
4. `store` edit the data monitor (`time` and `current_node` to `store`)
5. The data is syncing to `device`
6. `device` edit the data monitor (`time` and `current_node` to `device`)

Answer (score 0):

Use custom_on_update and custom_on_insert of the sym_trigger table defining an item table trigger. Initialize it with an SQL script that will update/insert a row in the monitoring table with the changes of the item table. Of course declare a trigger on monitoring table to have it synced from a device to store and from store to corp.

Comment: But now the problem is how to edit the same data monitoring row for one action? Example: 3 insert actions take 3 rows, and also 3 update actions take 3 rows. So the below node is just edit the monitoring data without insert it again

Comment: that's why you have custom_on_update field that can be used to update a row in monitoring table

Comment: CMIIW, custom_on_update is for adding custom update trigger on related table. I mean for edit monitoring data is when you have insert one row then the monitoring data (insert action) is inserted, and at 2/3 tier node just only edit the monitoring data. After that you update the same row then the monitoring data (update action) is inserted, and did same like before. From that, you have 2 data monitoring (insert and update) but only have one row data.

Comment: not necessarily on the same table. give it a try and see if it works for you

Comment: On `corp`, `item` table create (via trigger) a `monitoring` row. Then `item` and `monitoring` table is sync to `store`, so `item` table will create (via trigger) a `monitoring` row again, total is 2. And also in `device`. Total 3 `monitoring` row (`corp`, `store`, `device`) just for 1 `item` row. How to handle this? So I can just use 1 `monitoring` row for one action not 1 `item` row

Comment: No, it wont. Triggers are disabled when data is loaded from a sync. Give it a try, don't believe me ;)

Comment: why custom trigger is only created in source table in case one way sync? and how to create in target table too?

Comment: trigger is defined on a schema (if specified) and on its table. linking a trigger to a router via sym_trigger_router decides where the trigger gets created. use sync_on_incoming_batch to have it triggered on the target

Comment: Yes. But in one way sync, trigger only created in source node that defined in sym_trigger. Other words, I want to create custom trigger through SymmetricDS, especially in target node table